# 920828 - how to open and build a VS2010 solution in precise?

Tags: windows, c++, ide

Is it possible to open a `VS2010 solution` in an IDE environment and build it and get the same `output` in ubuntu? 
I mean pressing `F5` runs the program (maybe via Wine) in the same way?

I don't mean `.Net` or `C#`. The projects in the solution are all `pure native C++`.

Answer (score 1):

The entry in WineHQ rates [Visual Studio 2010](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22306) as bronze. Which in this case means it installs and runs, but won't build a project.

Your next best bet would be to install vmware or virtualbox and then install Windows and Visual Studio 2010.

Alternatively you could build your code with Linux native tools/IDEs. Depending on the libraries you depend on and the C++ Standard you conform to, this should be feasible.

Comment: thanx 4 ur reply
using virtual environments is not achievable because of my low memory.
for first solution, i couldn't install VS2010. it ended with lots of errors.
for the third solution, what IDE may open exactly the same .sln file and build it?

Comment: Apparently MonoDevelop supports '.sln'-files. You can get it from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest)